# Не открываются страницы в Google Chrome на Android при запуске из терминала

Tags: android, google-chrome, shell

Вытягиваю с помощью "скрипта"  название страниц  моего сайта  из заранее подготовленного файла. В файле каждое слово с новой строки.
Проблема в  том  что  порой он вытягивает ровно ничего. Передаю поисковые слова в браузер chrome на android.  Видите ли вы ошибку в коде ? Может быть вы сделали какие то изменения ?  Тестирую на  телефоне с рут и busybox.Запускаю скрипты в termonal Emulator.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su

a=$(shuf -n 1 /расположение/до/текстового.txt)

am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main "http://sait.ru/Search/$a"
```

Причем в терминале  пишет  что строку вытягивает правильно.Но браузер запускается на  пустой странице.Ссылка не открываться.Вот часть кода из терминала .Функция  в terminal emulator:  Кодировка по умолчанию UTf , отключена

```
Starting : intent { ac= android.intnt.action.ViEW dat=http://ссылка/search/  + cpm=com.andoid.chrome/com/google.android.apps.chrome.Main }
```